# C - Initilizing an array of pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to initialize an array of pointers in c, i succeed to initialize(It is in a struct) it but when i try to print it inside the method it do work but if i try to print it in the main it don't work

that's what i did:

```
typedef struct File
{
  char fileName[Max_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
  char* listOfFiles[];
} File;

struct File dependencies[MAXIMUM_FILES];

void findListOfFiles(char *line, int i, int currDepend)
{
  int idx=0,numOfFiles=0;;
  while(line[i]!='\n')
  {
    char name[Max_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
    while(line[i]!=',' && line[i]!='\n')
    {
      name[idx]=line[i];
      i++;
      idx++;
    }
    name[idx]='\0';
    dependencies[currDepend].listOfFiles[numOfFiles]=name;

    if(line[i]=='\n')
    {
      break;
    }
    numOfFiles++;
    i++;
    idx=0;
  }
}
```

if i try to print it in the main it didn't work but if i try to print it inside the method it do work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an array local  to the method,

```
char name[Max_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
```

Here, you assign the address of the array to your pointer.

```
dependencies[currDepend].listOfFiles[numOfFiles]=name;
```

However, When the method is over the array is gone as well. And your pointer is pointing to garbage

---

```
char name[Max_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
```

What you are doing now is,

```
Array:   [abc][def][ghi][jkl][mno]
Address  111  112  113  114  115 
         name

[]  []  []  []
222 223 224 225 
listOfFiles
```

By doing,

```
dependencies[currDepend].listOfFiles[numOfFiles]=name;
```

you do

```
[111]  [111]  [111]  [111]
222 223 224 225 
listOfFiles
```

instead of,

```
[111]  [112]  [113]  [114]
222 223 224 225 
listOfFiles
```

But, you can't do this by just copying string by string,

```
dependencies[currDepend].listOfFiles[numOfFiles]=name[i]; // example
```

Because, again after the method is over the strings do not exist.

You need to allocate dynamic memory such as using [malloc](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~mgiuca/253/malloc.html)

Answer (score 0):

`name` is local to the function, use `strcpy` to copy it to `listOfFiles`. Note that you must allocate memory for `listOfFiles` and the individual `char *`s it holds.